# Javascript Number Input Countdown

Tags: javascript

I want to make a countdown website, everything works fine, but it dont takes the numbers which are in the textboxes, i already enabled that only numbers can be entered. Everytime i enter some numbers, it shows NaN:NaN.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>Pizza Timer</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../0../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
    <body id="test" background="pizza.jpg">
        <h1 class="text-center"><strong>Pizza Timer!</strong></h1>
        <p class="text-center"><small>The Best Pizza Timer In The World!</small></p>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <div class="timer">
            <span id="time">The Timer Will Start When You Click The Button!</span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container">
                <input id="input1" class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Minutes" />
                <input id="input2" class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Seconds" />
                <button id="timerstarter" class="btn btn-success" onclick=buttonTimer()>Start!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var number1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
var number2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;

function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    var countdown = setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            alert("Your Pizza Is Ready!");
            clearInterval(countdown);
        }
    }, 1000);
}

function buttonTimer (number1, number2) {
    var Minutes = number1*60+input2,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(Minutes, display);
};
```

Comment: need to ParseInt to both number1 and number2

Comment: `var Minutes = number1*60+input2` What is `input2`? Shouldn't it be `number2`? You should really check your console for errors. Press `F12` in Firefox or Chrome and click the console tab. Chances are you'll see a few `Undefined` errors.

Comment: `parseInt` takes a string. you are already doing the math with it even before its a number.

Comment: fixed input2 -> number2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call

```
onclick=buttonTimer()
```

without args, but this function take two params

```
buttonTimer (number1, number2)
```

so in your case them both *undefined*

Next: this line

```
document.getElementById('input1').value
```

return string, so you should parse it before use with *parseInt*, or *parseFloat*

So, seems you should move lines

```
var number1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
var number2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;
```

to function *buttonTimer* like this

```
function buttonTimer () {
    var number1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('input1').value,10);
    var number2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('input2').value,10);
    var Minutes = number1*60+number2, //possibly this better rename to Seconds
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(Minutes, display);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

modify your code as follows:

```
var number1 = document.getElementById('input1');
var number2 = document.getElementById('input2');

function buttonTimer () {
  var Minutes = number1.value * 60+ number2.value,
      display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(Minutes, display);
};
```

Comment: @ramin, you forget parse values before doing math operation

Comment: sure, i assumed that we are not going to write exact answer here, we just need to solve conceptual problems, people must get through details by themselves, right? anyway, thank you reminding me my mistake